# Регулярное выражение для поиска подстроки из символов в строке

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение `^(\d{4,7})$` Оно валидно для поиска строки вида **123456**, на данную строку оно реагирует положительно. Но как модифицировать данную регулярку, чтобы найти подобную подстроку **123456** в строке вида:

```
Вася сегодня съел 123456 яблок
```

Я пытался добавить * в конце регулярки, но не помогло. Подскажите, что не так, в регулярках не силён, словарик не помог. Всем заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте границу слова

```
String regex = "\\b\\d{4,7}\\b";
```

Или блоки предварительного просмотра вперёд/назад:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\d)\\d{4,7}(?!\\d)";
```

Если шаблон `\b` стоит перед `\d`, то перед цифрой не должно быть буквы, цифры или знака подчёркивания. Если шаблон `\b` стоит *после* `\d`, то *после* цифры не должно быть буквы, цифры или знака подчёркивания.

Блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<!\d)` означает, что непосредственно перед цифрой не должно быть другой цифры. Блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!\d)` означает, что непосредственно после цифры не должно быть другой цифры.

[Демо-код на Java](https://ideone.com/J9NicK):

```
String s = "Вася сегодня съел 123456 яблок";
String regex = "\\b\\d{4,7}\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
} // => 123456
```

Comment: Метод find() отработал валидно, но matcher.group(0) крешится с сообщением "No successful match so far" Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK А вы дважды `.find()` использовали в коде? Должно быть именно так, как в ответе. А `System.out.println` в Android Studio надо заменить на `Logger.d(matcher.group(0))`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я 1 раз вызывал, сейчас всё гуд.