# Нужно удалить из строки всё, кроме слова Windows, пробелов и цифр

Tags: java

Вот какой код есть, но не знаю что написать в регулярке, чтоб удаляло то что мне надо

```
    String str1 = "BATTERY_CAPACITY=1, OS=Windows, MEMORY_ROM=4000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1000, CPU=1.2, DISPLAY_INCHS=18";
    String str2 = str1[1].replaceAll("[^(0-9\\.\s)]|[^Windows]","");
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне на ум приходит substring(indexOf( "Windows"),indexOf( "Windows")+ "Windows".length())

Comment: Вы вопрос сформулировали как-то странно

Comment: просто первый раз вопрос задаю

Comment: Есть строка str1, из нее надо удалить все, кроме Windows цифр и пробела, так, чтобы получилось

Comment: 1 Windows 4000 1000 1.2 18

Comment: [Вот ответ на твой вопрос , ток добавишь свой паттерн ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741964/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно в данной задаче нужно выбрать "значения" из пар `ключ=значения`, удаляя запятые и оставляя пробелы.

Такую задачу решить гораздо проще при помощи следующих выражений:

```java
String str1 = "BATTERY_CAPACITY=1, OS=Windows, MEMORY_ROM=4000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1000, CPU=1.2, DISPLAY_INCHS=18";

// удалить все символы до знака `=` кроме пробелов или запятые
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("[^=\\s]+=|,", "");
System.out.println(str2);
// -> 1 Windows 4000 1000 1.2 18

// удалить заглавные буквы/`_` и знак `=` или запятые
String str3 = str1.replaceAll("[A-Z_]+=|,", "");
System.out.println(str3);
// -> 1 Windows 4000 1000 1.2 18
```

---

Также можно отфильтровать входную строку и выбрать из неё необходимые совпадения `Windows` или последовательности из цифр, пробелов, и точек:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Windows|[\\s\\d\\.]+");
String str2 = p.matcher(str1).results()
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
// -> 1 Windows 4000 1000 1.2 18
```

Или же можно искать любые значения после знака `=`, разделённые запятыми (оба вида разграничителей помещаются в группы без захвата `(?:)`):

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:=)([^,]+)(?:,?)(\\s*)");
String str4 = p.matcher(str1).results()
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1) + mr.group(2)) // группа 1 - значение, 2 - пробелы
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
// -> 1 Windows 4000 1000 1.2 18
```